# Chinese character forbid

Tags: php

I have a web form, and I'd want the user while filling the form to not include any Chinese single quotes/double quotes in a textarea, how can I do that ?

Comment: You cant' really forbid him to insert them, but you'll have to double check what have been entered after the form validation.

Comment: But could you post your code to tell me how ?

Comment: I won't write the whole code for you, the best way is to try yourself and post questions here if something goes wrong with your code.

Comment: Admit it, you just don't know how to, either.

Comment: Ofc. Next time you'll ask for something, try to do some research beforehand.

Comment: Is the goal of this to prevent them being used for SQL injections? If so, either use PDO with prepared statements, or mysql_real_escape_string()... don't try to roll your own system! If it's for some other reason, you could combine the PHP filtering with some JavaScript which will monitor the text area for changes, and delete any characters you don't want after they type them. Mind you, the PHP would still be required for security purposes, the JS is just to make it more user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the form content and check it against a list of non accepted characters:

```
$formContent = $_GET["formcontent"];
$badCharacters = array("'", "‘", "“");
$cleanResult = str_replace($badCharacters, "", $formContent);
```

The bad characters array has the quote signs you dont like (if they are the standard quotes you will need to escape them) then the str_replace function goes through the form data replacing each one with an empty string. You should do proper escaping and security before this of course.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent user from typing into form element you must use client side scripting aka JavaScript.

Simple way is handling the `onkeypress` event:

```
<textarea onkeypress="return CheckKey(event);"></textarea>​
```

And having such code:

```
var arrForbiddenCodes = [97, 98, 99];
function CheckKey(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrForbiddenCodes.length; i++) {
        if (arrForbiddenCodes[i] === keyCode)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}​
```

This will block characters based on their *key code* - in the above code, the lower case "a", "b" and "c" letters will be blocked. To find key code of specific character, add `alert(keyCode);` to the function and just type that character into the textarea.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/bChHx/).

Answer (score 0):

you could add some javascript that uses a regex to restrict the entry to alpha or alpha and numeric (or any additional characters you want).

```
<script language="javascript">
function blockChar()
{
    var str = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    if(str.match(^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```